# Division in iOS Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, math, currency, division

Not terribly familiar with Xcode or Objective-C but trying to learn. Hopefully someone can help me out with a problem I'm having.

I have two fields, one called `price` and one called `units` and I'm trying divide the inputs of the cells by each other and then display the result with the correct currency of the 'nationality' of the device when a button is pressed.

So far I have of the action of the button I have;

```
- (IBAction)calculate:(id)sender {
    int x = [price.text floatValue];
    int y = [units.text floatValue];

    int calc_result = x / y;

    self.result.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", calc_result];

}
```

which outputs a result into a label field WITHOUT the decimal remainder.

How can I get it to display the decimal remainder to 2 decimal places and put in front the currency found from the 'nationality' of the device.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I hope you know this is **not** C#!?

Comment: Also, learn C before trying to make iOS or OS X apps. Your problem is trivial (how do you expect an `int` to hold fractional numbers?), and if you don't master C before getting into Objective-C, you'll have **serious problems.**

Comment: Thanks for the comments, learning whilst doing!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using an integer here:

```
int x = [price.text floatValue];
int y = [units.text floatValue];
int calc_result = x / y;
```

You should use a floating point number:

```
float x = [price.text floatValue];
float y = [units.text floatValue];
float calc_result = x / y;
```

Comment: This doesn't help in itself. The two other variables need to be `float`s too, else 1. the `float` values will be truncated to integers, 2. the division will be also a truncating integer division.

Comment: That’s true, I noticed the third `int`, not the other two… which where calling `floatValue` “correctly”.

Comment: @ChrisBarlow Again, I stringly suggest you please **learn C well** before continuing. Do yourself a favor :) It will be much easier later if you learn C now.