# How to display divided numbers in UILabel iOS

Tags: ios, uilabel

There are 2 textfields named as "liter" and "kronor". The user will type in two numbers, with decimals, in here.

I have a label where I want to divide "kronor" with "liter" (kronor/liter).

```
- (IBAction)prischeck:(id)sender {
    float x=[_kronor.text floatValue];
    float y=[_liter.text floatValue];
    float z= x/y;
}
```

Have I done it right?

Comment: yes it is correct ,what u need

Comment: A little searching on this website would've helped you bigtime. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17515691/2834868

Comment: You're calculating `z` but not doing anything with it -- the result is simply lost.

Comment: exactly. I want to display z in a label

Comment: literpriset.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", z];

Comment: @user3531671 re:"I want to display z in a label". Have you tried my solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
literpriset.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f", z];
```

or

```
literpriset.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f / %f = %f", x, y, z];
```

if you need to display also x and y.